# Artifcatory rest API to list all the Repositories

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am looking for a artifactory REST API that would *list down all the repo-keys*. If it could provide some more information then that would be really nice.

I looked up the Artifactory REST API documentation, but couldn't find one.

Did I miss anything ? Any other alternative ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I expect you're just looking for [GET /api/repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetRepositories).

This gives you the repo key, type, package type, description, and the URL of each repository, and you may filter by type or package type.

Comment: THank you @DarthFennec. This really helps

Comment: I want to filter the repository by its type, like list only the local or remote repository. How do I do it?

Comment: Add e.g. `?type=local` to the url

Answer (score 0):

For jFrog cloud, below API should list all repo details. Pass username and password using HTTP basic authentincation headers.

HTTP GET https://jFrog-cloud-domain-name/artifactory/api/repositories

Below is sample JSON response.

```
[
    {
        "key": "ABC",
        "description": "ABC Repo",
        "type": "LOCAL",
        "url": "https://<jFrog cloud domain name>/artifactory/ABC",
        "packageType": "GitLfs"
    },
    {
        "key": "DEF",
        "description": "DEF Generic Repo",
        "type": "LOCAL",
        "url": "https://<jFrog cloud domain name>/artifactory/DEF",
        "packageType": "Generic"
    },
    {
        "key": "XYZ",
        "description": "XYZ repo",
        "type": "LOCAL",
        "url": "https://<jFrog cloud domain name>/artifactory/XYZ",
        "packageType": "Maven"
    }
]
```